# How to generate an extended F key press (F13-F20)?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I need to submit an extended function key (like <kbd>F17</kbd> or <kbd>F17</kbd> ) to a program that runs in the terminal (I use the default `gnome-terminal` but could use another if it works there).

Is there a way in Ubuntu 11.04 to generate those key hits? I'm searching for something like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to generate <kbd>F17</kbd> (what I currently use in Reflection under Windows).

My keyboard is set to generic 105 keys PC with the US Qwerty layout.

Answer (score 2):

`xmodmap` may be the program to look into here, though it looks like it will take some fiddling. There is some discussion about using xmodmap to simulate a super/fn key and generate F13-20 keycodes [here](http://www.firemountain.net/pipermail/novalug/2010-February/023698.html). You need to find they keycodes currently used for Shift-F7 using the technique in that link, then remap them in your ~/.Xmodmap file. So for example if your Shift-F7 keycode was 320 your ~/.Xmodmap would look like:

```
keycode 320 = F17
keycode 321 = F18
```

A couple of the comments [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/use-the-windows-key-for-the-start-menu-in-ubuntu-linux/) look pretty useful for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at it soon (i.e. not marking it as the accepted answer yet).